# community.postgresql.postgresql_query raises `Failed to import the required Python library (psycopg2) on YYY's Python XXX/ansible-venv/bin/python3.7`

Tags: python, postgresql, ansible, psycopg2, python-3.7

I am running an Ansible playbook with virtual environment `ansible_venv` activated.

My playbook get struck here

```
collect data from DB

  localhost failed | msg: Failed to import the required Python library (psycopg2) on YYY's Python XXX/ansible-venv/bin/python3.7. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter
```

where XXX is hidden path.

the task `collect data from DB` is :

```
- name: collect data from DB
  community.postgresql.postgresql_query:
  
    login_host: '{{ db_host }}'
    login_user: '{{ db_username }}'
    login_password: '{{ db_password }}'
    db: '{{ db_database }}'
    port: '{{ db_database_port }}'
    
    query: "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = '{{ my_table }}')"
  
  register: qres
```

The machine which runs this playbook does not have access to the internet, so I have manually installed these packages on my machine:

```
/home/myuser/XXX/ansible-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2
/home/myuser/XXX/ansible-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2_binary-2.9.6.dist-info    
/home/myuser/XXX/ansible-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2_binary.libs
```

In order to do this, I have downloaded these packages on another machine with direct access to the internet, by using the terminal command `pip install psycopg2-binary`, then copied the files to the "ansible machine".

Theyr permissions and user are the same of the others modules installed there.

At path `/home/myuser/XXX/ansible-venv/lib/` I don't have any other interpreter than `python3.7`.

However, I am still getting the same error.

### update

The error is raised only on localhost (YYY in my example).

tasks using the `community.postgresql.postgresql_query` on other machines work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by rebuilding anew the ansible virtual environment on a machine having direct access to internet (machine2) and then moving it to the machine which didn't (machine1).

on machine1:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

on machine1

```
virtualenv ansible_venv

source ansible_venv/bin/activate
```

reinstalled the modules

```
cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install
```

installed psycopg2-binary

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

compressed and moved the `ansible_venv` folder to machine1 via `rsync`